# Error BAD_USER_INPUT when mutation create user in apollo-client v.3.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, frontend, apollo-client

**Spesification**

- Library

  - ReactJS v.16
  - Apollo Client v3.0.0
- Mutation

[image]

- Query (GET_ALL_USERS)
  [image]

**Problem**
When i'm starting to make mutation from Front-End for creating new users, it gives me error.
[image]

Here's the code.

```
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';

import { REGISTER_USER } from '../../../gql/mutation';
import { GET_ALL_USERS } from '../../../gql/query';

import { Button, Modal, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

    const ModalCreate = ({ show, onClose, variables, refetch }) => {
        // state for check input component
        const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState('ACTIVE');
        const [value, setValue] = useState({
            full_name: "",
            email: "",
            phone: "",
            address: "",
            password: "",
            group_id: "Admin"
        });

        useEffect(() => {
            if (show) {
            document.body.classList.add("modal-open");
            }

            return () => {
                if (document.body.classList.contains("modal-open")) {
                    document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
                }
            };
    }, [show]);

    // handler input
    const onChange = event => {
        setValue({
            ...value,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    // handler mutation for create data
    const [register, { error, loading }] = useMutation(REGISTER_USER, {
        onCompleted: (data) => {
            refetch();
        },
        onError: (err) => {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
    })
    
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(value)

        register({
                variables: {
                    input: {
                                group_id: value.group_id,
                                full_name: value.full_name,
                                email: value.email,
                                phone: value.phone,
                                address: value.address,
                                password: value.password
                        }
                    }
        })
    } 
    

    return (
        <Modal show={show}>
        <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title> <span>FORMULIR AKUN PENGGUNA</span> </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <Form onSubmit={ onSubmit }>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>Role Akun</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Select aria-label="pilih user role" name='group_id' value={ value.group_id.toString() } onChange={ onChange }>
                        <option>Admin</option>
                        <option>Admin RJ</option>
                    </Form.Select>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>Nama Lengkap</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control name="full_name" value={ value.full_name.toString() } onChange={ onChange } />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="email" name="email" value={value.email.toString()} onChange={ onChange } />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>Phone</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" name="phone" value={ value.phone.toString() } onChange={ onChange } />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" name="address" value={ value.address.toString() } onChange={ onChange }  />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="password" name="password" value={ value.password.toString() } onChange={ onChange } />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" >Submit</Button>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
                    Close
                </Button>       
            </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    );
    };

export default ModalCreate;
```

**Question**

1. How to fix BAD_USER_INPUT error code from front-end ?
2. in OnCompleted object, should i call GET_ALL_USERS query after mutation?
3. How to update the UI after creating user based on my code ?

Any help will be appreciated, thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your screen shot for the input values doesn't correspond to the error message. In the error message it says that the `username` is missing. Your `RegisterInput` input type (not shown) probably has that field marked as required.
2. If your UI needs to display all users, sure.
3. If you `refetch` your all users query then the UI should update automatically.